# SwiftyJSON - 'inout JSON' is not convertible to 'JSON'

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, swifty-json

I'm facing a JSON parsing issue I've no idea how to fix.

I need this part of the JSON data

`"columns": {
    "created_at": "DESC",
    "id": "DESC"
 }`

to be stored in a `[String: String]?` optional dictionary. So, this is the code I'm using:

```
self.columns = json["columns"].dictionary?.map { 
(key, value) -> (String, String) in
            return (key, value.stringValue)
}
```

This however produces a compiler error:

> 'inout JSON' is not convertible to 'JSON'

I should probably add that this is part of a pretty large piece of JSON data, and this is the only one causing issues.

Any clues would be most appreciated, I'm kind of stuck on this one.

Comment: Michal, Did you look at what it is trying to parse to figure out why it cannot parse it? print("self.columns") and post that. It obviously doesn't conform to a JSON object, so what is it?

Comment: @user3069232 this is what's returning from a request for this value:
`"columns": {
    "created_at": "DESC",
    "id": "DESC"
  }`
Should have probably added that to my original post, I'll do that now.

Answer (score 0):

Michael, I parse JSON with routine, cannot help but think it is a little more simplistic than yours, but it works :) filesQ.enqueue is an array in essence it adds the fields I want to.

```
func jsonParser(json2parse: AnyObject, field2file: String) -> Int {

    if (json2parse is NSDictionary) {
        for (key,value) in json2parse as! NSDictionary {
            switch (value) {
            case is NSDictionary:
                self.jsonParser(value as! NSDictionary, field2file: field2file)
                break
            case is NSArray:
                self.jsonParseArray(value as! NSArray, field2file: field2file)
                break
            case is NSString:
                parsedJson[key as! String] = value
                if (key as! String == field2file) {
                    let file2file = self.parsedJson[field2file] as? String
                    filesQ.enqueue("ignore", theFile: file2file!)
                }
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return(filesQ.qcount())
}

func jsonParseArray(json2parse: AnyObject, field2file: String) {
    for (item) in json2parse as! NSArray {
        self.jsonParser(item, field2file: field2file)
    }
}
```

Please send me back a copy if you managed to improve it!