# simpler way to evaluate (5 + 4) * 2 using recursive enum

Tags: swift, recursion, enums

I'm new to Swift and is trying to learn the concept of recursive enum. I saw this code snippet in "swift programming language 2.1".

```
indirect enum ArithmeticExpression {
    case Number(Int)
    case Addition(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)
    case Multiplication(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)
}

func evaluate(expression: ArithmeticExpression) -> Int {
    switch expression {
    case .Number(let value):
        return value
    case .Addition(let left, let right):
        return evaluate(left) + evaluate(right)
    case .Multiplication(let left, let right):
        return evaluate(left) * evaluate(right)
    }
}

//evaluate (5 + 4) * 2
let five = ArithmeticExpression.Number(5)
let four = ArithmeticExpression.Number(4)
let sum = ArithmeticExpression.Addition(five, four)
let product = ArithmeticExpression.Multiplication(sum, ArithmeticExpression.Number(2))
print(evaluate(product))
```

However, it seems to me that the statements above are a verbose way to evaluate (5 + 4) * 2, I was just wondering if there is an simpler way to evaluate ( 5 + 4) * 2 using recursive enum?

Comment: Examples are just examples. It's unlikely this would be useful code, outside of building a calculator. Finding additional uses of recursive enums is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: yeah, good point. It is hard to learn new concepts as a beginner but will try my best. do you have any suggestions? Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An enum than can contain values of the same type as itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find uses for recursion in many problems; say you want to parse some JSON code, this SO post uses a recursive method.

[SwiftyJSON - 'inout JSON' is not convertible to 'JSON'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598834/swiftyjson-inout-json-is-not-convertible-to-json/35622866#35622866)

Recursion is a difficult subject; that many students find hard; but you will find plenty of examples of it in the higher echelons of the coding world, the real world.

B-Tree searches use recursion too!! Your solution just reminded me.