# How to cast single Json Field to String?

Tags: ios, json, swift, casting

```
let list: Array<JSON> = json.arrayValue

for element in list {
    print(element["id"])
    print(element["name"])
    print(element["url"])

    var imageUrl:NSURL?=NSURL(string:(element["url"]as?String)!)
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial - http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/10/how-to-parse-json-with-swift-2/

Comment: i try to make var f=element["name"] as? String but i get back null then print f

Comment: Try this code to parse out your JSON. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598834/swiftyjson-inout-json-is-not-convertible-to-json/35622866#35622866

Comment: Thanks for your answer .I fount the solution.